# MobileFirst Adapter, manipulate or read the FINAL JSON result output

Tags: json, ibm-mobilefirst

Is it possible to collect the final JSON data output that comes from an adapter and eventually sent to the client.  The goal is to manipulate the output before it is finally sent back to the browser/client.  For example:

```
/* security { errors: ['SomeError'], isSuccesful: true } */
```

Into:

```
/* security { errors: [''], isSuccesful: true } */
```

This feature is available in a J2EE filter, I don't know if we want to go that low level.

Is it possible to use an authenticator for this scenario?

For example:

```
public class CustomAuthenticator implements WorkLightAuthenticator {
    public AuthenticationResult processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, boolean isAccessToProtectedResource)
            throws IOException, ServletException { }
}
```

Comment: What is your end goal here, to remove all errors from the response? You are not required to process it / do something with it in the app...

Comment: Mainly for 'security' reasons.  The response returns data like the javascript filename and line number, sometimes stack trace information.  It is a information leakage vulnerability.  But in terms of use cases, this is available with standard J2EE through the HttpServletResponseWrapper  if you wanted to manipulate output.  I was wondering if something is available an API to manipulate the response for the Worklight response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using JavaScript adapters there is no built-in option to do so. It is possible however to add a servlet filter to the WAR as you suggested.

If you are using Java adapters (starting MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.0), there is a "WLFilter" which is pretty much similar to a servlet filter except that it does not have to be in the WAR file - it is in the adapter itself (since it is a *Java* adapter).